# Using Scanner in Initialize method in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java.util.scanner

I am sorry if this is a trivial problem that I am having, but I cannot figure this out. I am using two Scanners inside a Initialize method in JavaFX Controller class. First one uses comma as delimiter, and it works fine. The other one uses dot as delimiter and has a String as stream. That other one won't work. Is there a problem with dot as delimiter? I am getting NumberFormatException at line where I declare int day.

My input format example from file ponude.txt is Kontiki, Kusadasi, 26.06.2013.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


    public class FormController implements Initializable{
        ArrayList<Ponuda> ponude = new ArrayList<Ponuda>();

        @FXML Button bt1;

        @FXML RadioButton rb1;
        @FXML RadioButton rb2;

        @FXML TextArea ta1;

        @FXML TextField tf1;

        @FXML private void bt1Click(){

        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
            File file = new File("ponude.txt");
            BufferedReader br=null;
            try {
                br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String trL = null;
            try {
                trL = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while(trL!=null){
                Scanner sc=new Scanner(trL);
                sc.useDelimiter(",");

                String agency=sc.next().trim();
                String destination=sc.next().trim();



                Scanner scInner = new Scanner(sc.next());
                scInner.useDelimiter(".");

                int day=Integer.parseInt(scInner.next().trim());
                int month=Integer.parseInt(scInner.next().trim());
                int year=Integer.parseInt(scInner.next().trim());
                //System.out.println(scInner.next().toString());

                Datum datum;


                try {
                    trL= br.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                scInner.close();
                sc.close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useDelimiter` uses a regular expression as its argument. The dot character is used in regex to `.` match any character so needs to be escaped to be interpreted literally

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\\.");
```